# Plumbing/piping diagram symbol identification

Tags: plumbing, water, heat-pump, planning, floorheating

I have this diagram schematic from the 50-page manual of the heat pump unit and there are symbols that are not explained anywhere in the documentation and I would like to understand them.

I tried to google those symbols first but to no luck.

1. [image]

---

2. [image]

---

3. [image]

---

4. [image]

---

5. [image]

I guess the first one is some sort of air vent (but the side triangle with the cross is confusing) and the fifth is some sort of closing valve (but again that arrow under it is confusing)

Here is the whole schematics for better context:

[image]

and full diagram:

[image]

The location is Europe, UK/Germany.

Comment: Location the heat pump is from might help.  Symbols might be different in Europe than North America

Comment: @crip659 fair point. location is indeed Europe (shall add it to the post)

Comment: Sanity check: have you tried websearching "plumbing schematic symbols"? Some can also be guessed from context; TMV is probably Temperature Mixing Valve, especially since it is hooked to both hot and cold water lines and it appears to feed a shower head.

Comment: @keshlam yes, I did try that prior to asking here. I managed to track down all other symbols with success only these 5 that are mentioned in the question remained. for example, I found #4 to be "hydrant" which is obviously wrong within this setup

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer (whom you haven't specified) to ask _them_ what their symbols mean?

Comment: @servant0 I found the "hydrant" also, but think it may be something functionally similar, like an outlet or tap. It would make sense to have drain valves in those locations.

Comment: @FreeMan indeed I did. no reply from them so far (1 month passed since then). the manufacturer is Daikin. I also asked the vendor, but they have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#2: By where it is in the flow, I'm guessing pressure-limiting make-up valve, with gauge.  That would make #4 just a pressure gauge.

#3: This is in the flow for household water but not for heating water. Water softener or filter?

I'd suggest comparing the schematic with your actual installation. Of course the schematic only shows a typical setup, but by tracing the pipes you may be able to identify devices that occur at those points in the flow and see whether the symbol might make sense for them (or look up symbols used for those devices andsee if they match).

Comment: Re: #3 It's in the "fill" section for the underfloor heating (UFH?) section, so water conditioning of some sort does make sense.

Comment: "actual installation" is actually non-existent (I'm trying to build the whole thing on my own based on the schematic & common sense)

Answer (score 1):

#1. Looks like a pressure relief valve?

[image]

#3. Maybe a pump?

#4. Drain valve?

#5. shutoff valve:

[image]

The arrows like under 5 are just showing the direction of flow, not part of the symbol I think (see arrow above STR for example).